# Working with html forms in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, forms, scroll, ionic-framework

```
<form ng-submit="update()">

     <label class="item item-input item-floatinglabel">
          <input type="text" ng-model="word">
     </label>
     <button class="btn btn-primary"ng-click="OnClick()">Get Words</button>
</form>
```

This is the current form I have. console logging "word" currently returns the word that's input however for some reason when I attach an `<ion-scroll> </ion-scroll>` around the form it only returns as "undefined". Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object in controller and use its properties as models like below.

```
     <label class="item item-input item-floatinglabel">
          <input type="text" ng-model="content.word">
     </label>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Get Words</button>
</form>
```

In your controller you can get the value like

```
$scope.content.word
```

Check the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ztM3Cg0AKe11wdQNrdV4?p=preview)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've done this. The code was not formatted properly so I apologise. The issue is with <ion-scroll>.